# Set AWS IAM Keys when creating Application from CLI

Tags: java, aws-opsworks

I am writing a deploy process from TeamCity to OpsWorks and when a new branch is deployed, create a new application on our development stack and deploy that application. The only thing I have not figured out is how to get the access key / secret key across with the CLI createApp call so that when the deploy app call is made, the s3 archive can be accessed.

Can anyone shed some light on how to resolve this, best practices, etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, I did eventually solve this issue. You can achieve this with custom JSON on the Stack or via the create-deployment CLI task's --custom-json parameter. It seems to be better practice to me to keep the IAM keys on the stack itself but with a development deploy task, the app names are undefined so it is simpler to put them in a shell script called by TeamCity which then triggers the deployment on Opsworks.

The JSON layout for the stack is: 
"deploy": { 
    *shortappname*: 
      { "scm": 
        { "user": *access-key*,
          "password": *secret-key-id* 
        }
      }
  }

The same layout works for the create-deployment, just wrap in outer brackets and escape strings properly.